# Not sure where to install node packages on Windows 10

Tags: npm

I'm having trouble installing node packages. I know that packages are now installed to AppData\Roaming on WIN10, but for me this is an issue because my company's login script makes my user profile set to another drive, for example U:\
So when I use npm to install a package, like typescript, the package gets installed to the wrong directory and a global package is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my .npmrc file to the below resolved the issue.

prefix=${APPDATA}\npm

Thanks to [nodejs npm global config missing on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536872/nodejs-npm-global-config-missing-on-windows/27052679#27052679)