# How to perform a clean install of NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Every time I try to run npm on Windows 10, I get `Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs"'`

- I have deleted `%Appdata%\npm` and `%Appdata%\npm-cache`.
- I have deleted `c:\program files\nodejs`, checked that `c:\program files (x86)\nodejs` does not exist, and tried to install NodeJS in `c:\nodejs` instead to get rid of the space in the directory name.
- I have uninstalled NodeJS and searched through the Windows registry, removing every reference to NodeJS.
- I have tried to use NPM to update NPM to a different version, but I only get the same error.
- I have removed all references to Node folders from environment variables and paths.
- Of NodeJS versions I have tried Latest **LTS Version: 12.16.3** (includes **npm 6.14.4**), and Latest **Current Version: 14.2.0** (includes **npm 6.14.4**).
- I have tried using Chocolatey to install NodeJS, it made no difference.

Every time I reboot, reinstall NodeJS, and try to use NPM, I get the same error.

When I try to check what version of NPM is actually installed, the answer is ... the same error.

How do I eradicate all NodeJS and NPM related files and settings from Windows 10 so that I can perform an actual clean install, without having to resort to the nuclear option, formatting the drive and reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after ripping my hair out, as well as half of the installed software on my PC, I continued googling, and eventually stumbled on the solution by investigating some file paths mentioned in this question: [nodejs npm global config missing on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536872/nodejs-npm-global-config-missing-on-windows).

Apparently, there is a config file `%userprofile%\.npmrc` which is relevant somehow. On my own computer, this file contained the text `prefix=C:\Program Files\nodejs"`.

If that looks familiar, it's because it's the string in the error message that has been plaguing me. When I emptied the file, npm started working again, just like that.

Comment: .npmrc tells npm its own configuration. This file is very helpful when you're using a cache layer in front of npm hosted elsewhere. This is typical in an enterprise environment