# Configure global nprmrc file location in Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, .npmrc

In Windows, I want to change the default global npmrc location, how can I do this?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html#per-user-config-file?

Comment: Yes, I want to define global file , not per user.

Comment: But the path you describe is to the per-user file. The global file is next one down in the linked docs.

Comment: Where the global file is located in Windows?

Comment: Looks like it's in AppData/Roaming by default: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15536872/3001761

Comment: So this is the problem I'm facing, AppData it's a folder inside C:\Users\<user>, I want the global .npmrc file to be elsewhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs npm global config missing on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536872/nodejs-npm-global-config-missing-on-windows)

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536872). Right? - Downvoting instead of flagging as duplicate is not very helpful, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran `npm config set prefix C:\npm` to change the prefix of the global `npmrc` location.

And then `npm config get globalconfig` to get the exact expected global location (which is `C:\npm\etc\npmrc`).

I navigated to this location and defined my global `npmrc` there (I had to create the `etc` folder myself.